# What to do in case of a non EU national leaving the aiport without a passport stamp?

Tags: airports, passport-stamps, frankfurt

Me and my mom arrived in Germany at Frankfurt airport. We flew to Frankfurt from Skopje via Ljubljana.  We passed passport control in Ljubljana, but in Frankfurt, we headed towards the baggage claim without passing passport control and without a passport stamp. She is an EU national, but I am not. Will passport control ask questions upon departure? I will be staying for one month. What should I do in this situation?

Comment: Where were you arriving from?

Comment: From Skopje to Ljubljana and then Ljubljana to Frankfurt.

Comment: Did you pass passport control in Ljubljana?

Comment: Yes, we did pass passport control in ljubljana.

Comment: Slovenia is in Schengen

Comment: I know that EU nationals can travel within schnegen countries without passport stamps. But I am not an EU national. Does that also apply in my case?

Comment: You should have gotten a passport stamp in Ljuljana...

Comment: I did get a passport stamp at Ljubljana airport.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You arrived from Slovenia, which, like Germany, is in the Schengen area, a group of countries which have largely abolished border controls between each other. For the purpose of border control, you were effectively on a domestic flight.

You'll go through (exit) passport control when you leave the Schengen area. Here they'll check how long you've been in the Schengen area as a whole - which exact countries you've been  isn't important.

Comment: Note that there are no passport controls for *anyone* travelling within Schengen, EU nationals or otherwise.  (The OP seemed to think that they needed to pass border controls since they are not an EU national.)